# Why is const variable necessary for template specialization over constants

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to understand constant template specialization. Consider following template function with one specialization:

```
enum class NodeType
  {A, B, C};

template<NodeType>
bool afunc()
{
  cout<<"calling generic"<<endl;
}

template<>
bool afunc<NodeType::A>()
{
 cout<<"calling specific"<<endl;
}
```

I am able to  invoke the specialized instance as follows:

```
 const NodeType x = NodeType::A;

  afunc<x>();
```

However, if i remove const then compiler complains about template/argument deduction failed. Why is the const necessary?

Comment: In C++11 and newer, you don't need a const variable; you can use an expression (including function calls) that can be evaluated at compile-time and the "constexpr" keyword.

Answer (score 7):

Templates are a compile-time only thing. If you remove `const` then `x` is no longer a compile-time constant, and therefore can't be used for template arguments.

Also note that `x` is only a compile-time constant because you define it as such, with the initialization.

Comment: Obviously :). Thanks.