# Template argument deduction fails when passing enum

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to insert an enum parameter into a constexpr function. I have done this in the past and it always worked... except in this case. This case is only special in that I'm calling a factory function first. But apparently C++ doesn't see through this. What can be done?

Those are my errors:

```
<source>: In function 'constexpr auto operator+(some_enum)':
<source>:30:28: error: no matching function for call to 'signal<1, state>(std::nullptr_t)'
   30 |     return signal<1, state>(nullptr);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:37: note: candidate: 'template<bool set, some_enum S, class ... Ts> constexpr signal_str<sizeof... (Ts)> signal(Ts ...)'
   23 | constexpr signal_str<sizeof...(Ts)> signal(Ts... Args)
      |                                     ^~~~~~
<source>:23:37: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:30:28: error: 'state' is not a constant expression
   30 |     return signal<1, state>(nullptr);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:30:28: note: in template argument for type 'some_enum'
<source>:28:16: error: invalid return type 'auto' of 'constexpr' function 'constexpr auto operator+(some_enum)'
   28 | constexpr auto operator+(some_enum state)
      |                ^~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

This is my code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

typedef void* TaskType_t;

enum some_enum
{
    SOME_STATE = 1,
};

template <size_t N> 
struct signal_str
{
    uint32_t val_;
    std::array<TaskType_t, N> tasks_;
};


template <bool set, some_enum S, typename... Ts>
constexpr signal_str<sizeof...(Ts)> signal(Ts... Args)
{
    return signal_str<sizeof...(Ts)>{S, {Args...}}.val_;
}

constexpr auto operator+(some_enum state)
{
    return signal<1, state>(nullptr);
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(+SOME_STATE);
}
```

I'm using C++17 on xtensa-gcc 8.2.0 but it's the same with gcc 11 ([LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/6dvKar1PT)).

**EDIT**: This problem is different from "[Why is const variable necessary for template specialization over constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288856/why-is-const-variable-necessary-for-template-specialization-over-constants)" because enums are already constants. To showcase this the following DOES actually compile:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

typedef void* TaskType_t;

enum some_enum
{
    SOME_STATE = 1,
};

template <size_t N> 
struct signal_str
{
    uint32_t val_;
    std::array<TaskType_t, N> tasks_;
};

constexpr auto operator+(some_enum state)
{
    return signal_str<1>{state, nullptr}.val_;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(+SOME_STATE);
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/v54ndK63f)

So the problem IMHO is not the enum..

Comment: You cannot use a non-constexpr variable as a template parameter. In this case, `state` is not constexpr. Imagine somebody did `cin>>state; +state;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is const variable necessary for template specialization over constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288856/why-is-const-variable-necessary-for-template-specialization-over-constants)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you but no, see my edited answer.

Comment: "because enums are already constants" - enum values are constant; non enum variables, So your `state` in `operator+()` isn't a constant. In your first (variadic) example, you pass `state` as template parameter, so the compiler gives an error because `state` isn't a `constexpr` variable; in you second example you don't pass `state` as template parameter, so the compiler doesn't complaint.

Comment: @max66 That makes sense. But I can only pick up "state" as a variable inside the operator overload or do I even have a choice?

Comment: But why don't you initialize `val_`, in the variadic case, as you do in the second example? I mean... what about `template <bool set, typename... Ts> constexpr signal_str<sizeof...(Ts)> signal(some_enum state, Ts... Args) { return signal_str<sizeof...(Ts)>{state, {Args...}}.val_; }` ? So you can call `return signal<true>(state, nullptr);` inside the `operator+()`.

Comment: By analogy, "integers are already constants", but you can't do `void test(int count) { signal_str<count>(); }` Although integers are constants, `count` is not a constant. It is a variable.

Comment: @max66 Could do but it pollutes my interface. But I guess this is the way to go..